# Merge results from SelectMulti tuple

Tags: c#, tuples, ormlite-servicestack

here is my query

```
var query = db.From<DataModels.Task>()
    .Join<DataModels.Assignment>((task, assignment) => task.TaskID == assignment.TaskID)
    .LeftJoin<DataModels.Association>((task, association) => task.TaskID == association.TaskID)
```

note that one Task will have 1 or more Assignment and zero or more Association. So I'm effectively getting duplicate `Task` (tuple item1) for each assignment match and every association match. My `Task` object contains properties List and List that just need to be populated from the result set. Is there an easy way to merge these?

Here is what I have currently, which works but is not very efficient

```
var tasks = results.Select(x=>x.Item1)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TaskID)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToHashSet();
var assignments = results.Select(x => x.Item2).ToHashSet();
var associations = results.Select(x => x.Item3).ToHashSet();

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.TaskAssignments = assignments.Where(x => x.TaskID == task.TaskID).ToList();
    task.TaskAssociations = associations.Where(x => x.TaskID == task.TaskID).ToList();
}
```